# Ignite node is failing with "Too many open files" error

Tags: ignite, gridgain

Though I have set System File Descriptor limit as "300000" and Process File Descriptor limit as 32768, one of the Ignite node is failing with below error. What caused the issue and how to resolve this issue permanently.

```
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to accept connection: GridWorker [name=nio-acceptor-client-listener, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1592476701201, hashCode=1172182555, interrupted=false, runner=nio-acceptor-client-listener-#34]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$GridNioAcceptWorker.accept(GridNioServer.java:2948)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$GridNioAcceptWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:2874)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:533)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:285)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$GridNioAcceptWorker.processSelectedKeys(GridNioServer.java:2998)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$GridNioAcceptWorker.accept(GridNioServer.java:2928)
        ... 3 more
```

Comment: `LimitNOFILE=65535` in the service definition will allow ignite to open more files.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Ignite with persistence is very hungry for file descriptors: a cache might have 1024 partitions by default so that's 1024 files open in a cluster of single node.

You can decrease number of caches, number of partition in affinity function, have more nodes :) or bump the limit further.

Comment: is this issue caused by the ignite user process open files limits reached (it's set to 32768/node for ignite user) which is running the Ignite Service on the nodes? Do I need to set the open files limit for ignite user to "unlimited" to resolve the issue?

Comment: Yes, this is recommended.